# (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection refused - multiple Docker container networking

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have three Docker containers, one everything frontend (React) related, one backend (Fastapi Python), and a Postgres database.

I connected all containers to a network via `docker network connect`.
My frontend is able to communicate to my backend, I also can communicate to all of my containers from my machine.

But somehow I can't access the Postgres DB via Backend.

```
error establishing DB connection: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My code can't be wrong as I can connect via `python database.py` directly.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = Database("0.0.0.0", 5432, "postgres", "password")
    d.conn_execute("")
```

Here some snippets from the database class of the backend:

```
class Database():

    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def conn_execute(self, query) -> None:
        try:
            print(f"postgresql://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}")
            self.engine = create_engine(f"postgresql://{self.user}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}")
            with self.engine.connect() as connection:
                result = connection.execute(query)
                for i in result:
                    print(i)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error establishing DB connection: {e}")
```

It has to be a problem with the networking itself but I don't understand what additional step it needs.

Additional information:

I played around with Docker Compose, several ports and `localhost` and `0.0.0.0`, everything lead to the same error.

### Update

After trying for several hours I installed another database (MongoDB) which works like a charm.

So I believe it's a Postgres thing?

Comment: If you're running a separate docker container, you can't use `0.0.0.0` (which you shouldn't really use anyway), but use the name of your other container instead (which you haven't included, but might be something like just `db` or `postgres`). Docker usually provides name resolution so that the ip resolves to the correct container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how does my Python API get the hostname then? Hardcore it like `db`? And yes, usually I use `localhost`

Comment: You need to pass it as a configuration parameter.  Environment variables are easy to set (`docker run -e`) and access (`os.environ`) but there are definitely other options.  Note that this setup will be different again if you're running it in a cloud environment with a hosted database, for example, hard-coding `localhost` is not usually correct.

Comment: In an FastAPI app you usually use `BaseSettings` from Pydantic and override it through `.env` or through an environment variable: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/

Comment: not sure why this question gets a downvote, anyway: thanks for your support! @DavidMaze: can you give me an example command as I would like to have the host of the Postgres Container in the run command of my backend container.

Comment: something to add what confuses me, why can front and backend communicate already?

Comment: Alright I found this: `A container can always discover other containers on the same stack using just the container name as hostname.`

Comment: added an edit. I guess it's a Postgres thing?

Comment: I am using docker compose now and it works with using the postgres container name as the host in the backend. Thank you guys!